# Is there a way to combine data from flavours of different dimensions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

I've made 4 different flavours of the same app and published all of them on Play Store as free apps.

Now I'm making a paid version for each of them, and in order to achieve that I've created 2 new flavours: free and paid, and these flavours have a different dimension to the one of the 4 apps. The 4 apps have the "version" dimension and the free/paid flavours have the "mode" dimension.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is to set different version codes and names to each version/mode pair, e.g.: flavourAFree -> versionCode 1 / flavourAPaid -> versionCode 2

Here's my code:

```
flavorDimensions "version", "mode"

productFlavors {
    flavourA {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourB {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourC {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourD {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    free {
        dimension "mode"
    }

    paid {
        dimension "mode"
    }
}
```

An example of what I'm trying to achieve (not exactly these values):

```
flavourAFree {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

flavourAPaid {
    versionCode 4
    versionName "2020.2.0"
}
```

When I try syncing my Gradle script I get the following error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Flavor 'flavourA' has no flavor dimension.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is described in this [android article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2020.2"

    }

flavorDimensions "version", "mode"

productFlavors {
    flavourA {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourB {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourC {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    flavourD {
        dimension "version"
        ...
    }

    free {
        dimension "mode"
        versionCode android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        versionName android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".3"
    }

    paid {
        dimension "mode"
        versionCode android.defaultConfig.versionCode - 12
        versionName android.defaultConfig.versionName + ".0"
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but it'll create:

- flavourAFree with `versionCode = 13` and `versionName = "2020.2.3"`
- flavourBFree with `versionCode = 13` and `versionName = "2020.2.3"`
- flavourAPaid with `versionCode = 1` and `versionName = "2020.2.0"`
- flavourBPaid with `versionCode = 1` and `versionName = "2020.2.0"`

For more information I recommend [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf)

Comment: Actually what I'm looking for is a specific version for each version/mode paid. I've updated the example on my question for more clarity